# feature to print data from form with values in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, printing

I have created a page with multiple forms in view using codeigniter. I want to display a popup window for printing the data from the form and there is a print button in that window. but I do not know how to take the data in the form of it until the exit popup window for printing in codeigniter. can you help me for coding for this issue. honestly I've never made ​​the coding like this problem because I am also a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

So you are a beginner, great. Here you have some ideas to try. **This solution use jQuery to get server data, put it into a dynamically created iframe and print it (useful for CI, WP, whichever).** That's what you want, mmm???

1.- jquery stuff

```
// <input type="button" id="print_me" data-form_id="101">
$("#print_me").live("click", function() {
    var form_id = $(this).data("form_id"); // get value 101
    $.post(
            // url to server where you get data to print
            window.location.href,
            {
                // vars sent to server to get data to print
                form_id : form_id // send form_id=101
                // etc
            },
            // output.contents have content to print
            function(output) {
                // create iframe
                var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
                ifrm.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // put content into the inframe
                    $(ifrm).contents().find("body").html(output.contents);
                }, 1);
                // print when iframe is loaded
                ifrm.onload = function() {
                    ifrm.contentWindow.print();
                }
            }, 'html');
});
```

2.- server process

```
$form_id = $_REQUEST['form_id']; // here we receive our data
ob_start();
// echo HTML formatted data to print
$contents            = ob_get_contents(); // $contents store all echoed HTML
ob_end_clean();
$output['contents']  = $contents; // wrap in $output
echo json_encode($output); // echo json encoded data
exit; // you must exit here!
```

You must to investigate deeply in every one of these steps. Once you achieved your goal you will have learned A LOT. Good Luck!